# How to split 2 numbers into the equal ranges in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I have table called `layers`. It looks like this:

```
| ID | TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS | DENSITY |
|----|-------------------|---------|
| 1  | 34440             |         |
| 2  | 41994             |         |
| 3  | 102824            |         |
| 4  | 19608             |         |
| 5  | 1287              |         |
| 6  | 4944              |         |
```

I found max and min values of the `TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS` column.

```
select
    MIN(total_subscribers),
    MAX(total_subscribers)
from
    layers;
```

Right now I need to split the max and min into 6 range and check if each  `TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS` included in a certain interval. Depending on which interval is included in `TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS`, I need to write the number of the interval in the `DENSITY` column.

For example in this table max value is *102824*, min value is *1287*.

**RANGES**:

```
102824 - 1287 = 101537
101537 / 6 = 16922.8333 ~ 16923
1 range: [1287-18210]
2 range: [18211-35133]
3 range: [35134-52056]
4 range: [52057-68979]
5 range: [68980-85902]
6 range: [85903-102825]
```

**FINAL RESULT**:

```
| ID | TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS | DENSITY |
|----|-------------------|---------|
| 1  | 34440             | 3       | < 34440 in 3 range
| 2  | 41994             | 3       | < 41994 in 3 range
| 3  | 102824            | 6       | < 102824 in 6 range
| 4  | 19608             | 2       | < 19608 in 2 range
| 5  | 1287              | 1       | < 1287 in 1 range
| 6  | 4944              | 1       | < 4944 in 1 range
```

Comment: Show desured result for shown data.

Comment: @Akina hello! I update my post with examples. Can you check it, please?

Comment: @jim-jones I update my post with more details and examples. Can you reopen the post, please?

Comment: @laurenz-albe I update my post with more details and examples. Can you reopen the post, please?

Comment: @marcin-orlowski I update my post with more details and examples. Can you reopen the post, please?

Comment: Does this work for you: `SELECT id, total_subscribers,range_id AS density FROM layers,(
WITH j AS (
SELECT min(total_subscribers) AS min_value,
  max(total_subscribers) AS max_value,
  (max(total_subscribers)-min(total_subscribers))/count(*) AS var
FROM layers)
SELECT 
  generate_series(1,(SELECT count(*) FROM layers)) AS range_id,
  generate_series(j.min_value, j.max_value-var, var)::INT AS range_min,
  generate_series(j.min_value+var, j.max_value+var, var+min_value)::INT AS range_max FROM j) j
WHERE layers.total_subscribers <@ int4range(j.range_min, range_max)
ORDER BY id;`

Comment: *34440 in 3 range* I see 2 ranges... look at [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46959613f24f16205701fab39ed4d56b).

Comment: @Akina you are right. _34440_ must be in _2_ ranges. This is my typo. Thank you for your answer. Well, in fact, I need to insert that values to `DENSITY` column to the existing table.

Comment: @JimJones I tried to test your code. Unfortunately, it raises such error: `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: @ int4range. Description: No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.`. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: Nothing prevents to convert SELECT to UPDATE. Of course, if `ID` is primary/unique.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek which postgres version are you using?

Comment: Check [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=515cc4fad647fd1a4601353a34d77461)

Comment: @JimJones my PosrgreSQL version: `PostgreSQL 11.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit`.

Comment: @Akina thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you reopen my question and post your answer, not like comment? I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=092c2e1d274a29cb6c708d762d321fce - it is also based on pg 11 and it works. Akina's also does the job, although it has a hardcoded number of rows

Comment: *Can you reopen my question* Look at my points... PS. I think it's easier to create new duplicated question (and delete this one) than wait until this topic is opened - reopening is too rare...

Comment: @JimJones *hardcoded number of rows* It is easy to replace hardcoded subquery with recursive CTE. Or use generate_series like in your solution - Postgres is not my favorite DBMS, so I don't remember all its possibilities.

Comment: @JimJones I don't know what's wrong with my database. Maybe I need some extension but your last code raises the same error as before. Something wrong with `@ int4range`. How do you think, what could be the reason of this strange behavior?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek aren't you forgetting a `<`, it is `<@ int4range` not `@ int4range`

Answer (score 2):

In a CTE calculate the min and max of `TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS` and also the length of each interval and then cross join to the table to make the calculation:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) minsub,
    ((max(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) - min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS)) + 1) / 6 dist
  from layers
)  
select l.*, 
  (l.TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS - c.minsub) / c.dist + 1 DENSITY 
from layers l cross join (select * from cte) c
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6xiNwPQQnRkyGYg8CGbxLp/2).
Results:

```
| id  | total_subscribers | density |
| --- | ----------------- | ------- |
| 1   | 34440             | 2       |
| 2   | 41994             | 3       |
| 3   | 102824            | 6       |
| 4   | 19608             | 2       |
| 5   | 1287              | 1       |
| 6   | 4944              | 1       |
```

In your expected results the row with `id = 1` should have `DENSITY = 2`, right?
Also your ranges should be:

```
1 range: [1287-18209]
2 range: [18210-35132]
3 range: [35133-52055]
4 range: [52056-68978]
5 range: [68979-85901]
6 range: [85902-102824]
```

so they are equally distrbuted.

Comment: Nice answer! Could you also share the code you used to get the ranges?

Comment: @wondim there is no code that gets the ranges. The cte returns the min of TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS =1287 and the distance to the 2nd range = 16923, so the 2nd range is constructed by adding these numbers. For the 3d range 16923 is added to the start of the 2nd range etc.

Comment: I found a way to get the ranges using `Select l.*, 
min(l.TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) over (partition by l.density) min_range,max(l.TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) over (partition by l.density) ma_range
From (with cte as (....) l)`. I don't know if it is optimal in large data but I don't notice a difference now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a combination of a [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-srf.html) and a [`int4range containment`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rangetypes.html) operation might be what you're looking for. The following code is tested on PostgreSQL 11 - see [`db fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=092c2e1d274a29cb6c708d762d321fce), but should also work with 9.4+.

Sample data

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE layers (id SERIAL, total_subscribers INT);
INSERT INTO layers (total_subscribers) 
VALUES (34440),(41994),(102824),(19608),(1287),(4944);
```

Query

```
SELECT id, total_subscribers,range_id AS density,range_min,range_max 
FROM layers,(
WITH j AS (
 SELECT min(total_subscribers) AS min_value,
   max(total_subscribers) AS max_value,
   (max(total_subscribers)-min(total_subscribers))/count(*) AS var
 FROM layers)
SELECT 
 generate_series(1,(SELECT count(*) FROM layers)) AS range_id,
 generate_series(j.min_value, j.max_value-var, var)::INT AS range_min,
 generate_series(j.min_value+var, j.max_value+var, var+min_value)::INT AS range_max 
FROM j) j
WHERE layers.total_subscribers <@ int4range(j.range_min, range_max)
ORDER BY id;

 id | total_subscribers | density | range_min | range_max 
----+-------------------+---------+-----------+-----------
  1 |             34440 |       2 |     18209 |     36418
  2 |             41994 |       3 |     35131 |     54627
  3 |            102824 |       6 |     85897 |    109254
  4 |             19608 |       2 |     18209 |     36418
  5 |              1287 |       1 |      1287 |     18209
  6 |              4944 |       1 |      1287 |     18209
(6 Zeilen)
```

Further reading: [`Common Table Expressions (CTE)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

select the Min value and divide the value of Max - Min by six as Range from `layers` as table b.

```
select min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) as M,
      (max(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS)-min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS))/6 as R from layers b
```

Then select all data from `layers` and using TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS to minus Min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) and divide by Range plus 1 then you can know which range(1-6) the TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS is.

```
 select a.*,((a.TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS-b.M)/b.R)+1 as DENSITY from(
      select layers.ID ,layers.TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS from layers )a,
      (select min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS) as M,
      (max(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS)-min(TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS))/6 as R from layers) b
```